# Add event on element load before it is in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to add an event when a DOM element is loaded but the element may not be in the DOM yet.

I could think of two solutions:

(i) attach it to `document.onload()`. It may take a while before it happens, if it happens so it is not ideal

(ii) checking the existence of the DOM element with

```
window.setInterval(function() {
      if (document.getElementById("id"))  /* do stuff */
    }, 100);
```

None of those is very elegant. Is there any better solution?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I don't want to use jQuery and want to have my script in the `<head>` without touching to the `<body>` of all the pages

EDIT2: The reason I am doing so is to track the proper loading of some elements and monitor how long they take to load and if they load properly.

Comment: No, I would rather stay away from that

Comment: Do you have any a priori knowledge about where in the DOM the element may be loaded?

Comment: What do you mean "when a DOM element is loaded but the element may not be in the DOM yet"? Specifically, what do you mean by "loaded"?

Comment: In modern browsers there is [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29) available.

Comment: @Lukas it can be anywhere in the `<body>`, would it matter?

Comment: @bfavaretto, I meant when the HTML element has bee has been added to the DOM tree (ie when `document.getElementById("myId")` returns something if I am correct)

Comment: @Teemu, thanks, that's a already an improvement over `document.onload()` though not universal

Comment: Considering your update: in my opinion, the developer tools provided by browsers are better suited to track the loading status/time of a page's assets (js, css, images etc). On Chrome, press f12 for to launch the dev tools, then click the "network" tab. Firefox + Firebug have a similar tab, and IE must have one too. I really don't see why trying to use js for that.

Comment: @bfavaretto Well, not quite, I want to track the performance of my website for all users (millions) in the less intrusive way, hence all my constraints. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Okay, that will be complicated (except for images - you can bind to their load event quite easily). Maybe this will help: http://code.google.com/p/jiffy-web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I think there is no better universal way.
A slight improvement is to to both: putting the check on `document.onload()` and at regular intervals (keeping a variable to make sure I don't do it twice).

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348702/can-an-element-be-in-the-dom-and-not-loaded) confirms that both are safe in terms of DOM being properly loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **event delegation** ..

Attach the click event to the document, and check for the element you want to run the function on..

```
document.onclick = function (event) {
  //IE doesn't pass in the event object
  event = event || window.event;

  //IE uses srcElement as the target
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var id = target.id;
  if( id === 'id'){
      clickEvent(id);
  }
};

function clickEvent(id){
  console.log("Elemennt with ID : " + id + "has been clicked !!")
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that would make sense for the click events but the event I am trying to track is actually the `onload` event itself. Basically I would like to make sure all the elements (including scripts and images) load properly and monitor how long it takes for them to load. I don't see how I can link that to a user generated event.

Answer (score 0):

MutationObserver is a Web API provided by modern browsers for detecting changes in the DOM. With this API one can listen to newly added or removed nodes, attribute changes or changes in the text content of text nodes.

You can read more here 
https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401