# Can an element be in the DOM and not loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add an event when a DOM element is fully loaded.
The only difficulty is that the element does not exist yet when my script runs.

My workaround is to test at regular intervals whether the element is in the script

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if (document.getElementById("myId"))
        /* do stuff */ ...; 
}, 100);
```

Now comes another issue, the first time I find the element, am I guaranteed that it is fully loaded?

- If yes it is perfect.
- If no, how can I test it? (when it is not loaded yet, I can append it to the `onload` event without any problem)

I don't have jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first time I find the element, am I guaranteed that it is fully loaded?

**Yes** unless the element is an`<img>` or an `<iframe>` which I believe it's not, so it's *"perfect"*.

Another important note is:

You can attach events to an element though it is not fully loaded, the fact it's in the DOM is sufficient for that task.

By the way, this is the difference between jQuery ready event versos javascript onload event.

Comment: @bfavaretto, do you want to add events to `<object>` ?!

Comment: No! But I believe it's async too. Honestly, I don't even know what that information would be useful for...

Comment: Hum, it may be an <iframe> too since it is a third party script... any solution if that's the case?

Comment: @MadEchet, you can attach events to an element though it is not fully loaded. I'm not sure what is your problem.

Comment: That list of elements isn't exhaustive... for instance, there's the `link` and `script` tags and they, too, have onload events.

Comment: If the Id exists but the element is not fully loaded I can add my tests in the `onload` iff the `load` event has not been fired (otherwise the test will never run). I need to make sure the element is not loaded yet to do so (if it is loaded, I can run my test immediately)

Comment: To put it differently, the issue is that I cannot define onload before it is in the DOM and there is no point changing onload after the element is loaded. If I want to do something onload I need to set the function between the time I add it to the dom and the moment it is loaded... how can I test that?